# Applescript in reverse?

Tags: variables, if-statement, applescript

& thanks for all the tips i've had here... this site is ace!

My question is, basically, how to correctly write my script. I've written an applescript, that works great for 1 variable, but i'll need to add hundreds of variables, and that'll currently mean adding hundreds of "if" statements.

So my script queries a FileMaker database & receives an input field (which is variable), i then want to open a the related textEdit file & read the text.

ie... FileMaker Pro returns "123", so i want to open textEdit file "123".

However, my script currently says If text returned is "123" then do *this*, else if text returned is "234" do *this*, else if text returned is "345" do *this*. To write this script with hundreds of "Ifs" doesn't make sense, but i can't get my head around swapping my script to say - returned value is "123" so use file 123.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: `open textEdit file (FileMaker Pro returns)` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply vadian,... I'm not too sure how that works in the larger context of a script, could you expand?  Here's what i have..... 

set onetwothree to read alias "macintoshHD:users:USER:desktop:onetwothree"
...

try
 if FileMakerResult contains "onetwothree" is true then
  tell application "TextEdit"
   set the text of the front document to onetwothree
  end tell
 else
  if FileMakerResult contains "twothreefour" is true then
   tell application "TextEdit"
    set the text of the front document to onetwothree
   end tell
  end if

Comment: Your question is very broadly so my broad suggestion is to set the result of the input field to a variable and pass that variable – maybe with adding file extension and the path to the parent folder – to TextEdit to open the file.

Comment: That'll work perfectly... thanks vadian!!